# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'list'

Tags: python, typeerror

I am getting a type error when I run this code. Please help me and thanks in advance.

```
input_delta = input("Enter your coordinate: ")
Delta_coordinates = [float(x) for x in [input_delta.split(",")]]
a = np.zeros((3, 3), int)
np.fill_diagonal(a, 100)
rotation_matrix = np.matrix([[-0.8660, 0.8660, 0], [0.5, 0.5, -1], [1, 1, 1]])
delta_abc = a*Delta_coordinates
mul_inverse = np.linalg.inv(a)
print(mul_inverse)
car = rotation_matrix*mul_inverse
cartesian = car*delta_abc
print(cartesian)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
[float(x) for x in [input_delta.split(",")]]
```

to this,

```
Delta_coordinates = [float(x) for x in input_delta.split(",")]
```

`input_delta.split(",")` itself returns a list, you don't need to convert that into a list again.